# Bad performance on live fuzzy search

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-web-api2, fuzzy-search

I've created a Web API using .NET Core and I'm currently struggling with an endpoint which return a top list of similar customer addresses related to an customer address as an input.

In short: I've an endpoint named **v1/customer/lookup** with the following body object:

```
{ customerName: "Facebook Ireland Ltd.", street: "4 Grand Canal Square", city: "Dublin"}
```

This live-lookup uses the Entity Framework to access an Azure database and references a table with 700k entries. The data I'm requesting are customer name, street and city and street. Same data are in a MS SQL database table.
I'm using an external library (https://nugetmusthaves.com/Package/DuoVia.FuzzyStrings) to make the check if a given customer name (e.g. "Facebook") is in my database and the match percentage which could be found.

For example:

```
Input customer name: "Facebook" -> in database "Facebook" -> 1.00 (100%)

Input customer name: "Fazebok"  -> not in database        -> 0.75 (75%)
```

A direct match lookup (100%) is quite fast and takes 200-300ms - even if the list has a count of 700k items.
When I'm not able to find a direct match I have to use the mentioned library to make a check for each item in the large list. This makes the API response take around 15 seconds.
If you might look for some code - that´s not my main focus. My question is how I can improve the general approach making the explained check.

Here is a short list of things I've tried:

1. While iterating over all the 700k items I check if a customer name (there are duplicated in the table which has to stay there) has already been checked by my fuzzy logic. This made the performance even worse since the lookup extended the response time.
2. Reduced the amount of columns being returned from the database -> no performance improvement

What I'm already doing is caching the database table for a given time that the first request might take a bit longer but the next requests are way much faster.

Maybe someone of you has a general procedure idea how this live fuzzy logic could be implemented. Would be very happy to hear some ideas!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the 700k database yours? There's a number of options but a simple one would be to define a soundex on their db records and populate it, and then do the soundex check against the whole table. Iterating over the entire 700k records checking each one individually is around the worst option I could think of.

Comment: Yes, it´s my database. Soundex sounds interesting...never heard of it - thanks!

Comment: Wow...this is awesome! Sped it up to 600ms! Thanks a lot!!